# Bolden Matched Search Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm writing a custom control which includes a text box input and an unordered list of items below it.  As the user types in the text box I would like for the matched text in the list to be bolded (wrapped in `<strong>` tags).

```
   //I use keyup so the value takes in to account the last keystroke.
   $('#filterList').keyup(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        //Clears the last function
        clearTimeout($this.data('timer'));

        //Runs the function after 400ms if no other keystrokes have taken place
        $this.data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
            var searchString = $this.val();

            $('li').each(function() {

                //Remove old strong tags.
                $(this).find('strong').replaceWith(function() {
                    return $(this).html();
                });

                //Here lies the issue... its close, but not quite there.
                $(this).html($(this).html().replace(new RegExp(searchString, "ig"), '<strong>'+searchString+'</strong>'));

            });

        }, 400));
    });
```

The problem I am having is I want the search to be **case insensitive**.  I was able to match the text appropriately but replacing it and keeping the original casing is becoming a challenge.  Also, I don't know how I feel about creating a regular expression out of a user's input.

Suggestions please!  Thank you in advance!

Comment: How does the data inside the `LI` elements look like? Does it only contain plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the [jQuery Highlight Plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html), you should be up and running in a few minutes.

As for replacing, you can use `'<strong>$&</strong>'` - `$&` will add the full text the regex matched. In this case, this is what you're looking for. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/cKVPY/

Comment: Thanks Kobi, $& was exactly what I was looking for.  The highlight plugin is cool too.